# DataRepeater displays different columns in each entry

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I have a `Repeater`. It gets data from some table . This table has say 3 columns.

What I want is if column1 = true column2 will be displayed and if column1 = false
column 3 will be displayed.

The layout will be something like this:

```
c1 = true  | c2
c1 = true  | c2
c1 = false | c3
c1 = true  | c2
c1 = false | c3
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Just using a `Literal` in your `Repeater` template:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rep"> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lit1" OnDataBinding="lit1_DataBinding"></asp:Literal> 
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then implement the `DataBinding`:

```
protected void lit1_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Literal lit = (Literal)(sender);
    lit.Text = ((bool)(Eval("Column1")) ?
        Eval("Column2").ToString() : Eval("Column3").ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything declaratively without code-behind:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# (bool)Eval("Column1") ? Eval("Column2") : Eval("Column3") %><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Alison, that's Nice . What about if Column1 is not bool ?

Comment: Not a problem.  What is Column1? From your question, it sounded like Column1 was a bool.

Comment: For that exact reason is why I rarely ever put any logic in the markup and use the `OnDataBinding` method.  You can then make the code as complex as you like.  Yes you can do it in the markup but it makes for logic and code in your presentation which I try to avoid.  Very few reasons to need C# code in your aspx code IMO.

Comment: Alison . Column1 is a string and it represents a type . I have two types represented by the two other columns . So, if type1 is written in column1 only column2 will be displayed . Actually, I have many types . That's why I can not use bool .